# Regex to extract two numbers with spaces from string

Tags: javascript, regex

I have problem with simple rexex. I have example strings like:

```
Something1\sth2\n649 sth\n670 sth x
Sth1\n\something2\n42 036 sth\n42 896 sth y
```

I want to extract these numbers from strings. So From first example I need two groups: `649` and `670`. From second example: `42 036` and `42 896`. `Then I will remove space`.

Currently I have something like this:

```
\d+ ?\d+
```

But it is not a good solution.

Comment: Do you mean something like `\d(?: ?\d)*`?

Comment: These extracts are from getting _innerText_ from _div_. So _\n_ its only part of string.

Comment: what about /\d+\s?\d+/g ?

Comment: You may use: `\\n(\d+(?: \d+)*)`

Comment: *I have example strings* - Are you sure these are literal strings and not *string literals*? Where did you copy the examples you posted on top of the question from? If these are string literals, you need `var matches = /^(\d+(?:\s+\d+)?).*\n(\d+(?:\s+\d+)?)/m.exec(str); console.log(matches[1].replace(/\s+/g, '')); console.log(matches[2].replace(/\s+/g, ''));`, see [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/uTJpZ9/1).

Comment: Why does this question have so many answers posted as comments? I would expect that experienced volunteers would already be aware that solutions should be posted as answers, not comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
\n\d+(?: \d+)?
```

- `\n` - Match new line
- `\d+` - Match digit from 0 to 9 one or more time
- `(?: \d+)?` - Match space followed by digit one or more time. ( ? makes it optional )

---

```js
let strs = ["Something1\sth2\n649 sth\n670 sth x","Sth1\n\something2\n42 036 sth\n42 896 sth y"]

let extractNumbers = str => {
  return str.match(/\n\d+(?: \d+)?/g).map(m => m.replace(/\s+/g,''))
}

strs.forEach(str=> console.log(extractNumbers(str)))
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to remove the spaces. Then the easiest way for you to do this would be to remove the spaces and then **scrape** the numbers using 2 different regex.

```
str.replace(/\s+/, '').match(/\\n(\d+)/g)
```

First you remove spaces using the `\s` token with a `+` quantifier using `replace`.

Then you capture the numbers using `\\n(\d+)`.

The first part of the regex helps us make sure we are not capturing numbers that are not following a new line, using `\` to escape the `\` from `\n`.

The second part `(\d+)` is the actual match group.

Comment: I simultaneously like this answer and I don't like it.  It is smart to remove the spaces first because they need to be removed anyhow AND this step serves to simplify the pattern logic.  However, it is not smart to sanitize the whole input string (doing unnecessary work) when you only need to remove spaces from the matches.  This is probably a "horses for courses" scenario whereby if the input string is _small_, then use this answer; if the input is _large_, then it may be better to match-map-replace.  I generally avoid making iterated function calls though.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var str1 = "Something1\sth2\n649 sth\n670 sth x";
var str2 = "Sth1\n\something2\n42 036 sth\n42 896 sth y";
var reg = /(?<=\n)(\d+)(?: (\d+))?/g;
var d;
while(d = reg.exec(str1)){
    console.log(d[2] ? d[1]+d[2] : d[1]);
}
console.log("****************************");
while(d = reg.exec(str2)){
    console.log(d[2] ? d[1]+d[2] : d[1]);
}
```

Comment: This answer is missing its educational explanation.